# Подсветка кода в javaFX приложении

Tags: java, javafx

Пишу JavaFX приложение - ридер, для чтения спец.файлов, содержащих код специфичного языка программирования.
И я хотел бы создать на форме своего приложения какой-то элемент, который бы позволит сделать стилизацию текста как код.

Пример кода из оригинального редактора
[image: пример кода]

Подчеркну, что код является специфичным, т.е. найти готовый стиль под него нельзя. Только написать.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, какие контролы я мог бы использовать для этого в JavaFx, или же какие-то готовые решения может быть уже существуют для этих целей.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

нашел похожую тему на stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114478/is-it-possible-to-set-different-colors-for-different-lines-in-a-javafx-textfield
там советуют использовать  RichTextFX для более сложной стилизации текста.

или можно глянуть документацию от оракла: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/text-settings.htm https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html